# @vite directive in dev mode inserts invalid path

Tags: laravel, vite

Good day.

- fresh installation of laravel
- correct address in .env APP_URL
- @vite(['resources/css/app.css']) is written in the blade template
- running npm run dev works fine

When I go to the local address of the site in html, I see the following:

```
    <script type="module" src="http://::1:5174/@vite/client"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://::1:5174/resources/css/app.css">
```

Styles are not loaded, changing styles does not automatically reload the page.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

::1 is the loopback address in IPv6. When using an IPv6 address in a URL, you must enclose the address in square brackets (e.g: http://[::1]:5174/). I don't know why vite inserts the wrong url on the page. Is this a bug or am I missing something? Anyway, in order for everything to work with a local enviroment, you can write in the vite.config.js file:

```
export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: '0.0.0.0'
    },
});
```